# What do you call a person who views things differently?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

Is there a particular word/phrase to describe a person who views things differently in a **positive** way? Or looks for new ways to describe a situation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [*lateral thinker*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lateral-thinking), perhaps?

> **lateral thinking** - noun [ U ]
>
> a way of solving a problem by thinking about it in a different and original way and not using traditional or expected methods

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: It's up to you, but I wouldn't accept answers immediately (unless it is exactly the answer you were looking for). Doing so may discourage others from posting their answers. You never know -- you might get a better one. Give it 24 hours is the general recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

The person hears (or marches to the beat of) a *different drummer*.

Answer (score 1):

*Innovator, rebel, revolutionary, free-thinker, non-conformist, iconoclast, radical* -- all can be positive in the right context.

For example, Steve Jobs was referred to as all of these, at various times in his life (and after his death).